# How to execute Drupal form without waiting? Ajax? Jquery?

Tags: forms, ajax

I am trying to code one of my first Drupal modules and hitting this problem.

I have a simple form in a custom module, that checks value of field_status and depending on if it is "down" or "up" executes one of two bash scripts "startup" or "shutdown" respectively. Here is the code:

```
function status_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   $node = menu_get_object();
   $status_code = $node->field_status_code[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
if ($status_code=="down") {
   $string = shell_exec('ssh startup);
   $node->field_status_code[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = "up";
   node_save($node);
} else {
   $string = shell_exec('ssh shutdown);
   $node->field_status_code[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = "down";
   node_save($node);
}

drupal_set_message($string);
return $form;
}
```

The submission button:

```
function status_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form['status'] = array('#markup' => block_content());
    $node = menu_get_object();
    $status = $node->field_status[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    if ($status=="down") {
    $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Start up'),
    );
    } else {
    $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Shut down'),
  );

}
```

The bash scripts have to take from 3 to 5 minutes, during which I'd like to entertain a user, but don't know how to "release" the browser window to do something else - ideally to start showing some improvised status bar because I know in PHP it is not possible to know the status of the process until it is really finished and sent back to user browser.

I tried to add `'#ajax' => array( 'callback' => 'status_form_submit'),` like so:

```
 $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Shut down'),
    '#ajax' => array( 'callback' => 'status_form_submit'),
```

however unfortunately it failed to execute the form.

Could anyone help me to properly apply ajax or jquery or direct me to another way of to get this done? Thanks for attention!

**Edit:**

With the modification suggested by 2pha, my Ajax button starts working but giving this error in a popup window:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: Service unavailable (with message)
ResponseText: #0  entity_extract_ids(node, stdClass Object ([field_status_code] => Array ([und] => Array ([0] => Array ([value] => down))))) called at [/home/dev/public_html/modules/field/field.attach.inc:191]
#1  _field_invoke(presave, node, stdClass Object ([field_status_code] => Array ([und] => Array ([0] => Array ([value] => down))))) called at [/home/dev/public_html/modules/field/field.attach.inc:914]
#2  field_attach_presave(node, stdClass Object ([field_status_code] => Array ([und] => Array ([0] => Array ([value] => down))))) called at [/home/dev/public_html/modules/node/node.module:1085]
#3  node_save(stdClass Object ([field_status_code] => Array ([und] => Array ([0] => Array ([value] => down))))) called at [/home/dev/public_html/sites/all/modules/custom/server/server.module:171]
#4  status_form_submit(Array ([status] => Array ([#markup] => Your server is currentlyRunning,[#tree] => ,[#parents] => Array ([0] => status),[#array_parents] => Array ([0] => status),[#weight] => 0,[#processed] => ,[#required] => ,[#attributes] => Array (),[#title_display] => before,[#id] => edit-status,[#sorted] => 1,[#validated] => 1),[submit] => Array ([#type] => submit,[#value] => Shut down,[#default_value] => 1,[#ajax] => Array ([callback] => status_form_submit,[wrapper] => block-server-server-status,[event] => mousedown,[keypress] => 1,…
```

**Edit2**

After little bit modification my code looks like below, but it is till giving the same error above:

```
function status_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form['status'] = array('#markup' => block_content());

   $node = menu_get_object();

    $form['nid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#default_value' => $node->nid,
    );

   $status_code = $node->field_status_code[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
   if ($status_code=="down") { $value="Start up"; } else { $value="Shut down"; }

 $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $value,

     '#ajax' => array(
     'callback' => 'status_form_submit',
     'wrapper' => 'block-server-server-status',
     ),

    );

$form['uptime'] = array('#markup' => block_uptime());
  return $form;
}
```

**Edit3**

```
<div id="block-server-server-status" class="block block-server">

    <h2>Server Status</h2>

  <div class="content">
    <form action="/server/141044310074320-1-1-22091820210112" method="post" id="status-form" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><p>Your server is currently</p><p class="status virt">Running</p><input type="hidden" name="nid" value="1">
<input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Shut down" class="form-submit ajax-processed"><p>3 days, 19 hours, 44:05 minutes (330245 seconds) uptime</p><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-29nkoOYINz8YhIWyfp9mALYxMKUZVKbkks6s6J3wGQM">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="Fz1c4yAkg0YwhMxzhs3X3a3aBwuEoE3t0JM1uhT3yd4">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="status_form">
</div></form>  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to set the 'wrapper' for your returned element.
This is what it says under the '#ajax['wrapper']' part of the [form api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax).
"This property is required for using AJAX requests in on a form element."

eg.

```
 $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Shut down'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'status_form_submit',
      'wrapper' => 'status-form-wrapper',
    ),
```

Which corresponds to the div wrapped around your form so javascript knows what dom element to replace with what is returned by your submit function.
So, if using the code above, you need to wrap your form with the id 'status-form-wrapper'.

```
function status_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['prefix'] = '<div id="status-form-wrapper">';
  $form['suffix'] = '</div>';
  $form['status'] = array('#markup' => block_content());
    $node = menu_get_object();
    $status = $node->field_status[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    if ($status=="down") {
      $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Start up'),
    );
    } else {
      $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Shut down'),
  );
}
```

NOTE: I am unsure if you can set 'prefix' and 'suffix' to the form element itself, if not, you will have to nest your form elements under the wrapper div.

**EDIT adding example of node id in hidden field.**

```
function status_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['status'] = array('#markup' => block_content());
  $node = menu_get_object();
  // ADDING THE HIDDEN FIELD HERE
  $form['nid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#default_value' => $node->nid,
  );
  $status = $node->field_status[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

  if ($status=="down") {
    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Start up'),
    );
  } else {
    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Shut down'),
    );
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately lines:  $form['prefix'] = '<div id="status-form-wrapper">';
$form['suffix'] = '</div>'; give WSOD. Without them:            
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: Service unavailable (with message)
ResponseText: EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7729 of /home/dev/public_html/includes/common.inc).

Comment: The form had already been nested in div with id "block-server-server-status". Replacing 'wrapper' => 'status-form-wrapper' in your suggested code with 'wrapper' => 'block-server-server-status', is giving: An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: Service unavailable (with message)
ResponseText: EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7729 of /home/dev/public_html/includes/common.inc).

Comment: Then I suspect your problem is with your call to `menu_get_object` as the current path in the ajax request is `system/ajax` so `menu_get_item' will not work in an ajax call. You are probably going to have to send an argument in the url that will allow you to load the appropriate node.

Comment: Could you please give some specific examples of how "to send an argument in the url that will allow you to load the appropriate node" as I am unfortunately not that much experienced? Thanks!

Comment: It would depend on where your form is being displayed. Is the form being displayed on a node page? If so, you could add a hidden form element containing the node id, then it should be available in the submit function.

Comment: The form is displayed in a block, which is placed on a node page using Display Suite module. But how exactly I should add a hidden element with node id? So confusing...

Comment: same way as you added the submit button except `'#type"=>'hidden'`, and `'default_value'=>node->nid`

Comment: '#type'=>'hidden' is hiding my submission button. With only 'default_value'=>$node->nid left it still gives the error. Please see the edit section above, as it is not convenient to add code in comments. Thanks!

Comment: ?.... I did not mean to add type=>hidden on your submit button, I mean create another form element of type=>hidden and give it a default value

Comment: sorry but it is not so obvious to me. Looking at my code above what should be another form look like? I really do not understand. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the answer showing how to add a hidden field to the form. This value should now be available in the submit handler. This should allow you to load the node without using the `menu_get_object()` function in the submit.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still giving: An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: Service unavailable (with message)
ResponseText: #0  entity_extract_ids(node, stdClass Object ([field_status_code] => etc .... :(

Comment: did you remove the call to `menu_get_object()` in the submit function?

Comment: I did not as it seems to be there in your code too. I've updated the whole peas under "Edit2", could you please take a look at it? Thanks!

Comment: I've added another Edit3 with the html code of the whole block. Maybe I am doing something wrong with 'wrapper' => 'block-server-server-status'?

Comment: If I remove return $form; part then the whole block returns with empty content.

Comment: Sorry, the function does need to return 'form' and you must remove the `menu_get_object()` from the submit function and use an alternative method to get the node. As you now have access to the node id in the submit fuction, you can use `node_load()`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17236/discussion-on-answer-by-2pha-how-to-execute-drupal-form-without-waiting-ajax-j).